# If I use an IocContainer at all, should it be used everywhere?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

We use an Ioc Container to resolve most of the objects in a project, however it seems like it might be innappropriate to use it everywhere.  At runtime, the user is in the context of a single company Id and it seems appropriate to me to pass that company Id in the constructor of, for example, a repository or unit of work.  We could use a parameter override for the company Id at runtime, but is there any benefit in using

```
var uow = IocContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>(new ParameterOverride("companyId", companyId))
```

as opposed to

```
var uow = new UnitOfWork(companyId)
```

OK, so I understand that I might want to create a different implementation of IUnitOfWork some time and I could then easily swap in the new implementation with Ioc configuration, but I am not convinced I will ever do that anyway.

Comment: Since you aren't sure, as a really quick half-way, why not just create a `UnitOfWorkFactory`. Internally it can return a new instance for now, and if in the future you decide to leverage the `IocContainer` it can be done easily without having to refactor a tonne of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are times when calling `new` is exactly what you want.  An example would be an object local to a method call or a narrow scope.

Model objects usually aren't under the control of an IoC container.  You instantiate one for each new session or request scope, using data passed to you from users that can never be known by the IoC container on startup.

Update: Honza Brestan's point about logical units is spot on.  The typical Spring layer arrangment is interface-based:

```
view->controller->service->persistence
```

Services use other services, model objects and persistence to fulfill use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I find the biggest advantage of IoC not in the implementation swapping (people hardly do that anyway in most projects), but in forcing you to divide your code into clearer logical units, which in general means it is unit-testable, manageable and easier to reason about as a whole.

With that in mind, I suggest deciding the "injection granularity" for yourself depending on what are the logical units of your project. It may be 5 larger modules, it may be dozens of different small connectors. Also as duffymo mentioned, `new` may be what you want for local/narrow scope.

Comment: "but in forcing you to divide your code into clearer logical units, which in general means it is unit-testable, manageable and easier to reason about as a whole." - amen and +1 from me.  Spot on.